# Add user information in additional or current model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have a "user model", which is managed by the gem devise. Right now, that model has only the most basic information (first name, last name, email, password).

Now I am wondering wether I should add additional user fields as an additional, associated model (e.g. named "userprofile") or just add the additional fields to the existing "user" model (profile picture, years of experience, description about the teacher etc.). What is the common practice?

I am looking forward your help.

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, add those kinds of "simple" attributes directly to the User model (i.e. years of experience, description, etc). As you add more complicated information about a user (e.g. job history), or if you have a significant amount of these attributes such that it might start impacting performance, you may want to start adding associated models. But otherwise it's probably not worth the added complexity.

Answer (score 1):

When you call current_user (or any devise helper method per se), it retrieves all the fields from the database for that user record, whether or not you need  'em.  So, it's better to have as lesser fields in the devise's user model as you can.  If you want to create a user profile with additional fields, better create a new associated model.